# PostgreSQL on Azure Linux VM - Command Not Found

Tags: linux, postgresql, azure

I setup a Ubuntu Linux server on an Azure VM and installed PostgreSQL 12. To access the server, I am using Putty to SSH in and execute commands. However, I keep encountering the error `command not found` for various commands. In an attempt to get this to work, I use `sudo` in front of the command, but that is when it prompts me for the password of postgres.  Reading online it looks like this is a password that should **not** be unlocked. I believe my issue is related to permissions of my admindj user that I setup, but with both Linux and PostgreSQL being brand new to me I am slightly struggling to wrap my head around how would I grant this access if that even is the true issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to find the location of pg_controldata by :

```
find /usr/lib -name pg_controldata
```

It can give something like

```
/usr/lib/postgres/12/bin/pg_controldata
```

Then you can put in your $HOME/.bashrc :

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgres/12/bin
```

And restart a new bash session, you will have access to pg_controldata

You may need to add in your $HOME/.bash_profile

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: Ok so I was able to navigate to where pg_controldata lives, but am still unable to call it. When trying to locate my bashrc file under my user account, I had to run vi ~/.bashrc but am not sure how/where to make the edit. I think I also made multiple files by accident as I'm not comfortable with LINUX commands just yet. Any advice while I try to figure this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: Figured out the command to use, but even when adding PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgres/12/bin to my .bashrc I still get the same command not found error. Yes I restarted my SSH seesion.

Comment: Can you type directly in your ssh session : `PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgres/12/bin` ?
and run pg_controldata. 
If still not working, make sure pg_controldata is in /usr/lib/postgres/12/bin.

Comment: I kept typing `.../postgres/...` instead of `.../postgresql/...`. I made the appropriate change in my .bashrc file and can now call the command after navigating to it.  Thanks!